# c++ Математический пример

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно записать это в с++

Comment: Как это получилось у вас?

Answer (score 1):

```
double a = std::sin(x * x);
return a * a * a;
```

Отдельная переменная используется, чтобы не вычислять синус трижды. Потребуется подключить заголовок <cmath>.